# redux-form and dynamic nested state

Tags: redux-form

I use redux-form v5.

state shape is:

```
{
    name: 'abc',
    parameter: 'asdf',
    namespaces: {
        namespaceA: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'],
        namespaceB: ['tag3', 'tag4', 'tag6']
        ...
    }
}
```

In order to connect static fields it was enough to specify them in fields array when I call

```
reduxForm({
   form: 'myForm',
   ['name', 'parameter'],
}, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyForm)
```

But how can I connect to individual keys of the 'namespaces' object?

The end goal is to display multiple pairs of Label - Input on the form, where Label will be namespaceA/namespaceA/... and Input will contain all the tags for the corresponding namespace.

Editing the input should only modify the corresponding array.

I can't really specify them the regular way, because keys are dynamic.

I think that I may need to generate forms per key dynamically but wasn't able to make it work yet.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this issue?